# sort Map by value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm looking for a simple way to sort a Map by value in javascript. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473854/javascript-map-like-array-sorting-and-adding) the function `Object.keys(myMap)`, but it returns an array of string. In my case, the keys are not strings but complex objects, then the result is not really good (array is empty...). Do you know another way?

**EDIT**

Explanation of my purpose : I have a `Map<myClass, Array<myClass>>`, and I want to sort this map wrt the length of values (arrays), from the shortest to the longest.

Comment: Sorting a map is not possible, since they use hashes internally. Can you explain with an example?

Comment: _the keys are not strings but complex objects_ Can you explain what is "complex objects" ?

Comment: @R3tep methinks OP mean [this Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: The question is very confusing because you talk about maps, arrays, objects and dictionaries all at the same time (they are all different things). And the code you have in the edit isn't even JavaScript.

Comment: @Grundy yes, is exactly that.

Comment: @FabrizioMorello possibly [Map.prototype.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys) what you need

Comment: @Juhana I really don't see confusion in my question. Where is the dictionary? My purpose is to sort [this Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) by value, where the value is an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). About code format, it is TypeScript, a superset of JavaScript, but that's not important

Comment: @FabrizioMorello Dictionary is in your tags

Comment: @R3tep I put the _map_ tag, but it turns in _dictionary_, I don't know why. Anyway, removed !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot sort a Map directly, but you can convert it to an array, sort it and create a new Map:

```js
m = new Map()

m.set({x:1}, [1,2,3]);
m.set({x:2}, [1,2,3,4]);
m.set({x:3}, [1,2]);
m.set({x:4}, [1,2,3,4,5]);
m.set({x:5}, [1]);

// can also use Array.from polyfill here
a = [];
for(var x of m) 
  a.push(x);

a.sort(function(x, y) {
  return x[1].length - y[1].length;
});  
  
sorted = new Map(a);
for(var x of sorted) 
     document.write(JSON.stringify(x) + "<br>");
```

Comment: the constructor `new Map(a)` doesn't work, it says "_Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target_". Should it be cause I'm coding in TypeScript and not in JavaScript?

Comment: @FabrizioMorello: can be... I don't know TS, is there a way to test it out online?

Comment: I don't know. Anyway, your solution seems correct, then since I asked a solution for javascript, I'll mark it as accepted.